# Downloading from GPS / changing SCR / not working

Tags: gps, coordinate-system

I use a GARMIN GPS;

I download my points from the GPS by using GPS tool;

I "try to" change projection (SCR) by changing layer property/specify SCR

Still, it not working and I cannot view my layer on my project...

Any help?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Also, what projections are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the layer CRS is **not** a reprojection.

Assuming you work with QGIS, you have to set your layer back to WGS84, then right-click on the öayer and `Save As ...` where you can choose a different file type (GPX must always be WGS84, but shapefiles can have any CRS), name and CRS.

Apart from that, Activating `On-the-fly-Reprojection` under `Settings -> Project Setings` should display your GPX file even on a project with a different **project** CRS. Project and layers then do not have to be in the same CRS.

Comment: Thank you... I don't no why, but On-the-fly-reprojection was not working in my "very old and full of layers" project. I start a new project, oppening each layer one by one and now, it working... The gpx file use the project CRS. THANK!